# Obtaining result in Frequency Domain using FFT in Matlab

Tags: matlab, fft

There are the two vectors: Time and Displacement (Don't know how to attach them here)[Displacement vs Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5XgN.jpg)

Vector displ.mat is the displacement vector obtained after running a dynamic response analysis under a load.

I want to obtain the fundamental frequency which can be easily picked up by plotting the two vectors using `plot(Time,displ)`. In this plot, one can easily see a sine wave with a frequency of roughly 0.5 Hz. So, I expect to see this peak of 0.5 Hz using `fft` function of Matlab.

Comment: Thanks ... But I am not getting you ... the code that I placed in the question has been borrowed ... So mainly I am unfamiliar with inside details of the code.

But the requirement is straight forward that the two vectors Time and Displacement can be plotted to reveal a Time history of displacement. 
I need to plot Frequency spectrum so on x-axis, I want to see Frequencies.

As a reference you can see the plot (Time vs Displacement) showing a frequency of 0.5 Hz.

Comment: I will prefer a simpler algorithm as an alternative.
I was expecting to see X-axis labelled as Frequency (Hz) after runing FFT command.

Comment: I just deleted the code. Now as a fresh look at the problem, say, if we want to do fft on a vectorised list of a variable 'displ'. Now as stated earlier, all I need is simply a Figure showing me the "Frequency (Hz)"

Comment: I've just deleted my previous comments. Just remember: DFT is not simple.

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Why do you think it is not working yet?

Comment: It was giving me the sample numbers on X-axis instead of Freq (Hz). 
Also, since the two vectors Time and Displacement are missing here so may be it is difficult for others to understand my question here.